# Git- made changes on a local branch, checked out master, and master is now broken

Tags: python, django, git

I am working on a Python/ Django project, using Git to manage my version control.

I recently made some changes on a branch called `conceptCalendar3`, and the changes I made broke my site.

I committed the changes to that branch, and then checked out `master`, which, I had branched from in order to create the `conceptCalendar3` branch. However, when I now to try to view my site from the `localhost`, on `master` branch (on which I have not made any changes since it was last working), I now get a message in the browser telling me that:

> This site can't be reached
>
> localhost refused to connect

The Python console is displaying a lot of output with error messages that I've not seen before:

> File "/Users/.../Documents/Dev/moonhub/moon/moon/urls.py", line 27, in 
>       url(r'^costing/', include('costing.urls', namespace="costing")),
>     File "/Users/.../.virtualenvs/moon/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/conf/urls/**init**.py", line 52, in include
>       urlconf_module = import_module(urlconf_module)
>     File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/importlib/**init**.py", line 37, in import_module
>       **import**(name)
>     File "/Users/.../Documents/Dev/moonhub/moon/costing/urls.py", line 2, in 
>       from . import views
>     File "/Users/.../Documents/Dev/moonhub/moon/costing/views.py", line 2900, in 
>       from projects.views import get_project_folder
>     File "/Users/elgan/Documents/Dev/moonhub/moon/projects/views.py", line 38, in 
>       from .forms import *
>     File "/Users/.../Documents/Dev/moonhub/moon/projects/forms.py", line 1207, in 
>       class PostDepMeetingForm(ValidatedForm):
>     File "/Users/.../.virtualenvs/moon/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/forms/models.py", line 257, in **new**
>       raise FieldError(message)
>   django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Unknown field(s) (meeting_date_time) specified for Survey

The 'field' that it seems to be complaining about, `meeting_date_time` is one that I added on the `conceptCalendar3` branch- but it doesn't exist in the code on the `master` branch...

I have tried running `git pull origin master` to ensure that I have the latest version of code from the live version of the project, but this tells me that everything is up-to-date.

So why can't I view a version of my site locally, and why am I getting these errors in the console?

**Edit**

I tried checking out an old commit, and at one point was in a `detached head` state- could it be that I am still in this `detached head` state, and so some of my code is point to `master`, but some of it is pointing to `conceptCalendar`? If that's the case, how would I check, and how would I resolve it?

Comment: If git tells you that your branch is up-to-date, then it's probably not a version mistake. Check out for other factors that can cause you those errors. Are they the same they used to be on you broken branch `conceptCalendar3` ?

Comment: What do you mean? What other factors could cause me those errors? I haven't made any changes to anything other than the files on my `conceptCalendar3` branch- so the files on `master` should be unchanged...

Comment: The last error in that list that is being displayed in the console indicates that there's an issue with a variable called `meeting_date_time`- that variable doesn't exist on my `master` branch (which is where I now am), but it did exist on `conceptCalendar3`- so it seems as though `masters has not been checked out correctly, or that something somewhere is still pointing to the other branch...

Comment: Check out @slezica 's answer, point number 3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Possible causes:

1. (Git) You forgot to `git add` files in the `conceptCalendar` branch, and they are still lying around when you `checkout` `master`.
2. (Python) You have stale `.pyc` files in your project. Remove them.
3. (Django) You forgot to `makemigrations` in the `conceptCalendar` branch
4. (Django) You ran `migrate` on the `conceptCalendar` branch, your database schema has changed, but now the code on `master` reflects the old schema. Rebuild your database, or migrate backwards.

I'm betting my money on this last point. From the error you posted, i'm thinking that maybe a `Form` is extending `ModelForm` for a `Model` that changed in the other branch. Check that all fields exist in the underlying model, and in the database.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I haven't run a `migrate` or `makemigrations` at all... as I didn't actually make changes to any of the models on the other branch... Because the changes I made on the other branch didn't work- I wanted to checkout `master` in its original state, to start my changes afresh

Comment: I tried checking out an old commit, and at one point was in a `detached head` state- could it be that I am still in this `detached head` state, and so some of my code is point to `master`, but some of it is pointing to `conceptCalendar`? If that's the case, how would I check, and how would I resolve it?

Comment: Checkout `master` and `reset --hard` to go back to a 100% clean repo. What about the field `meeting_date_time` of the `Survey` class? Does that exist in `master`? Is it present in the `Model`? The `Form` can't find it. Either it's not written in code, or it's not in the database

Comment: No, `meeting_date_time` does not exist in any classes/ models on `master`, and I'm not trying to use it in the `Form`. I was using it in the `Form` on the `conceptCalendar` branch- but as I mentioned in my OP, I broke the site on that branch, so decided to 'discard' it, and start afresh by creating a new branch from `master` (which was working at the time).

Comment: If I `reset -- hard` on my `master` branch now, what happens? I tried restoring previous working commits- and I think that may have been when `master` stopped working....

Comment: Are you sure that `meeting_date_time` is nowhere mentioned in your code? Do a search, using `grep` or your editor's search. Restart the Django server. Remove all the `*.pyc` files in your project. Actually that last one is a likely cause too, I'll add it to the answer

Comment: You say I may have forgotten to `git add` files on `conceptCalendar` branch- can I check that out again, and add them now, then switch back to `master`?

Comment: Yes, you can do that. `git status` will tell you if any files are not tracked in the current branch

Comment: Yes- I am sure that `meeting_date_time is not mentioned anywhere in my code- I have run a search in Sublime (the editor I'm using), and it can't find it anywhere...

Comment: Remove all the .pyc files, perhaps an old version is compiled with the field in it

Comment: I've just run `git status` on all of the branches that I have checked out today, and they are all clean. What/ where are the .pyc files? Is there any danger in removing them?

Comment: Ok, so I checkout out each of the branches that I've worked on today in turn, ran `git add -A`, & `git commit -m `message` again, and even though it displayed a message stating that `nothing to commit, working directory clean`, having now checked out `master` again, and browsed to the page at `localhost`, it is now working- thanks for your help!